# What does slide to verify field in UI do?

Tags: security, web

[image]

What's the purpose of the "Please slide to verify" field? Once we slide it it goes green. Does it determine the sliding was done by human or machine?

What is it known as in web technology?

Comment: `Does it determine the sliding was done by human or machine?` - Yes, it seems so.

Comment: Never seen before. Have they taken patent for that?